# If $a \in G$ and since all rings are of course closed in addition, then I know $(a+a) \in G$. Can I say that $2a \in G$ as well?

Tags: ring-theory

Let's say I have a ring $G$.  If $a \in G$ and since all rings are of course closed in addition, then I know $(a+a) \in G$.  Can I say that $2a \in G$ as well?  What I am getting at is this -- we have not "defined" the number 2 in this ring. Also, multiplication in $G$ could be defined differently.  So I think $(a+a)$ and $(a+a+a)$ are in $G$, for example, but $2a$ and $3a$ are not necessarily in $G$.  Am I thinking properly about this?

Comment: Generally, $na$ is defined to be $a$ added with itself $n$ times.

Comment: If your rings have unit (usually written $1$) then it is standard to identify $n \in \Bbb{N}$ with $\sum_1^n 1$ and then multiplication by $n$ in $G$ agrees with the standard convention in @MichaelMorrow's  comment (which works whether or not your rings have a unit). Note that $n = 0$ is possible even when $n \neq 0$ in $\Bbb{N}$. E.g., in the ring of integers modulo $3$, $3 = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  So $2a$ is this context can be different from (let's assume $2$ and $a$ are both members of $G$) $2$ "multiplied" by $a$ where multiplication is defined in some strange way in the ring.  So it would be good for me to use distinct notation when defining multiplication in the ring perhaps.

Comment: I don't know if you saw my comment before writing yours, but if $2$ in $G$ is defined(in a ring with unit) as $1 + 1$ as per my comment, then nothing strange can happen, so it is harmless (and standard) to use the same notation for multiplication by natural numbers as you do for ring multiplication (namely juxtaposition).

Comment: I posted my comment before I saw yours -- I see it now and this makes sense.  Thanks Michael and Rob for clarifying!